# Error in Prediction results of Named Entity Recognition Task

Tags: python, pytorch, named-entity-recognition, transformer-model

After training the NER Task with using RoBERTa Architecture, I got the below result

```
{
 'eval_loss': 0.003242955543100834,
 'eval_precision': 0.9959672534053343,
 'eval_recall': 0.9959672534053343,
 'eval_f1': 0.9959672534053343,
 'eval_accuracy': 0.9995624335836689
}
```

The result generally is quite high, as I expected. But here is my confusion, when I randomly input a set of sentences (out of the training set) to really know the model's performance.

My pseudo code:

```
def tokenize_and_align_labels_random(examples, tokenizer):
    tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(examples['tokens'], 
                                 truncation=True, 
                                 is_split_into_words=True)
    return tokenized_inputs
def preprocess_datasets(tokenizer, **datasets) -> Dict[str, Dataset]:
    tokenize_ner = partial(tokenize_and_align_labels_random, 
                           tokenizer=tokenizer)
    return {k: ds.map(tokenize_ner) for k, ds in datasets.items()}

address=Testing_Dataset[Testing_Dataset['address']==1]['text'].apply(clean_doc).tolist()

da_datasets_random_Test = preprocess_datasets(tokenizer,
test=Dataset.from_dict({'tokens':address}))

results=da_trainer.predict(da_datasets_random_Test['test'])

predictions=results.predictions
predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=2)
# Remove ignored index (special tokens)
true_predictions = [
    [label_list[p] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
    for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
]
```

I input the sentences with some words *that don't exist in the tokenizer vocabulary*, and the model will handle that part for me by automatically generating their sub token.

> That means the 'input_ids' will generate more token ids for presenting these cases, the problem is their predicted tags will also be increasing (based on how many tokens was delivered to the model).

For instance

- Input sentence: "Giao tôi lê_lai phường hai tân_bình hcm"
- Value after tokenizer:

  ```
  {
    'input_ids': [0, 64003, 64003, 17489, 6115, 64139, 64151, 64003, 6446, 64313, 1340, 74780, 2], 
    'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
  }
  ```
- Because tokenize of "lê_lai" is ['lê@@', '*l@@', 'ai']; of "tân_bình" is ['tân*@@', 'bình']; of "hcm" is ['h@@', 'cm']

The result I got after all:

```
['O','O','B-LOC','I-LOC','I-LOC','I-LOC','I-LOC','I-LOC','O','I-LOC','I-LOC', 'O']
```

In fact, their prediction should only have 7 tags for the input tokens, but now it was more than this. So do guys have any strategies for this (I got one that we can train the tokenizer with more tokens).

Comment: I think you just need to use something that maps from the wordpiece tokens back to real tokens, Huggingface and spaCy both have alignment tools like that. What it'll do is translate the tags for your subtokens back to the full tokens.